# Javascript - Why my stack implementation cause a lot of GC events?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I wrote a stack implementation in Javascript and make it as node module callled 'stack-js-implementation'.

You can check out the source code here:

```
function _StackItem(data, prev, next){
  this.data = data;
  this.prev = prev;
  this.next = next;
}

function Stack(size){
  this.maxSize = size;
  this.currentSize = 0;
  this.head = null;
  this.last = null;
}

Stack.prototype.push = function(data){
  if (this.head === null) {
    var newStackItem = new _StackItem(data, null, null);
    this.head = newStackItem;
    this.last = newStackItem;
    this.currentSize += 1;
  }else{
    var originalTopStackItem = this.head; 
    var newStackItem = new _StackItem(data, null, originalTopStackItem);
    originalTopStackItem.prev = newStackItem;
    this.head = newStackItem; 

    if (this.currentSize === this.maxSize) {
      this.last.prev.next = null;
      this.last = this.last.prev;  
    }else{
      this.currentSize += 1; 
    }
  }
};

Stack.prototype.pop = function(){
  var topStackItem = this.head;
  if (topStackItem === null) {
    return this.head; 
  }

  this.currentSize -= 1;
  if (topStackItem.next === null) {
    this.head = null;
    this.last = null;
    return topStackItem.data;
  }else{
    this.head = topStackItem.next;
    return topStackItem.data;
  }
};
```

I implement my own stack data structure because I want to limit the stack size. If the stack has reached the max size, execute `push` will remove the bottom-most element of the stack and push the new element to the top-most position of the stack.

I think if I use the traditional array it will spend a lot of time on moving, so I built it using linked-list.

After doing some tests, I find this implementation is quicker than array on pushing new element to the stack when the size has reached the max size.

But pushing the new element to the stack before it gets to the max size is slower than the array.

This is the test code I wrote:

```
var Stack = require('stack-js-implementation');
var s_own = new Stack(800000);
var s_internal = new Array();
var before, after;

console.log('--- own implementation ---\n');
before = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 800000; i++) {
  s_own.push(i);
}
after = Date.now();
console.log('--- Add Elements to Stack Time --- : ' + (after-before) + '\n');

before = Date.now();
s_own.push(1000);
after = Date.now();
console.log('--- Push Time --- : ' + (after-before) + '\n');

console.log('\n\n');

console.log('--- internal implementation ---\n');
before = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < 800000; i++) {
  s_internal.push(i);
}
after = Date.now();
console.log('--- Add Elements to Stack Time --- : ' + (after-before) + '\n');

before = Date.now();
s_internal.shift();
after = Date.now();
console.log('--- Shift Time --- : ' + (after-before) + '\n');

before = Date.now();
s_internal.push(1000);
after = Date.now();
console.log('--- Push Time --- : ' + (after-before) + '\n');
```

I run the profile(use `node --trace-gc test.js`) and find out the problem is that it caused a lot of GC events.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how pushing a new item on the stack when the stack is not yet full would cause any GC.  You create an object and insert it in the list.  There should be nothing to GC.  Once the list is full, the older object that gets kicked out of the list would be subject to GC if there were no other references to it.  What do you think is being GCed?

Comment: I run it use the command `node --trace-gc test.js` and I see a lot of GC events happened.

Comment: Then, you need to see what it is exactly that is being GCed. Your `.push()` by itself should NOT be causing GC before the list is full.

Comment: How can I get this information?

Comment: I'd first simplify your test to ONLY do a bunch of `.push()` operations where the stack stays under capacity.  See if there are lots of GC operations when doing ONLY that.  Don't even have any `console.log()` statements or timing.  Just the `.push()` operations.

Comment: But how can I know what step executes GC and what step does not ?

Comment: The concept behind GC is when a Javascript object that you previously created no longer has any code that refers to it.  It is said to be "unreachable" at that point and when the GC realizes that it is unreachable, then it can be freed.  Function calls with local variables also create objects that must be GCed since each call to the function creates a new function scope object - so an issue could be your 800,000 calls to `.push()` or to the `_StackItem` constructor.

Comment: I find the problem is cased by the `_StackItem` constructor. It causes a lot of GC events. But I don't know what is the reason ? Could you explain for me. Thanks

Comment: You could change this: `var newStackItem = new _StackItem(data, null, originalTopStackItem);` to this: `var newStackItem = {data: data, prev: null, next: originalTopStackItem};` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: How can there be no difference?  You said the `_StackItem()` constructor was causing lots of GC and we just removed that constructor?  All of those constructor calls are now gone.  I don't think I can help you unless you show an exact running piece of code (perhaps in a jsFiddle) so I know ***exactly*** what you are testing.  For example, if you're running it past the limit, then of course, there will be lots of GC.

Comment: FYI, when you hit the limit on your Stack, you could reuse the object you're going to kick out of the stack, thus preventing any GC from throwing the old one away and then creating a new one.

Comment: This is the version that has deleted the `_StackItem()` : https://jsfiddle.net/7vjgfLnc/

Comment: Original version : https://jsfiddle.net/3b0d35rd/

Comment: Really thanks your help.

Comment: In my Mac, I see no difference. But in other computer, I see there is a big difference.

Comment: @jfriend00  Finally I rewrote it use traditional Array instead because it is faster....